# Auto redirect in old paypal integration

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I have an old integration where payment values are posted to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
I want to change paypal account to a new one, so I changed "old email" to new one in `<input type="hidden" name="business" value="old email" />` 
Payment works, but it's not redirected to page in my server after payment.

1. Can I specify a redirect url in post values? Adding `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="my redirect url" />` only showed "Return to Merchant" button after payment, didn't automatically redirect to "my redirect url"
2. Where can I find the new identity token in my new paypal account? identity token is used in call back page,

```
    function get_call_back_vars($tx_token, $identity_token, $sand_box = false)
    { }
```

In the documentation of the above PHP function it says,
`$identity_token` - Identity token generated for you from Paypal (can be found at Web Reference Profile page) but couldn't find "Web Reference Profile"  page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return will not and cannot be automatic. In most jurisdictions a receipt has to be displayed. Changing accounts did not change this behavior; unregistered buyers must click to return.

The website payment preferences page is in your account settings. Here is a direct link to it: https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website

PDT is the second section.

Comment: Thanks very much @Preston PHX, your answer had all the details I needed